# Extract URLs from Google search result page

Tags: html, go, screen-scraping

I'm trying to grab all the URLs off of a Google search page and there are two ways I think I could do it, but I don't really have any idea how to do them.

**First**, I could simply scrape them from the `.r` tags and get the `href` attribute for each link. However, this gives me a really long string that I would have to parse through to get the URL. Here's an example of what would have to be parsed through:

> https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mh4u%20items&oq=mh4u%20items&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i59j69i60j0l2.1754j0j7/url?q=https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/&sa=U&ei=n8NvVdSvBMOsyATSzYKoCQ&ved=0CEUQFjAL&usg=AFQjCNGyD5NjsqOncyLElJt9C0hqVQ7gyA

The URL I would want out of this would be:

> https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/

So I would have to create a string between the `https` and `&sa` which I'm not 100% sure how to do because each really long string Google gives me is a different size so just using slice and cutting it up "x" amount of characters wouldn't work.

**Second**, underneath each link in a Google search there is the URL in green text. Right clicking that and inspecting the element gives: `cite class="_Rm"` (between chevrons) which I don't know how to find with goquery because looking for `cite` with my small function just gives me more long strings of characters.

Here is my small function, it currently does the first option without the parsing and gives me a long string of text that just takes me to the search page:

```
func GetUrls(url string) {

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(url)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    doc.Find(".r").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        doc.Find(".r a").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
            Link, _ := s.Attr("href")
            Link = url + Link
            fmt.Printf("link is [%s]\n", Link)
        })

    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library has support parsing URLs. Check out the [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package. Using this package, we can get query parameters from URLs.

Note that your original raw URL contains the URL you want to extract in the `"aqs"` parameter in the form of

```
chrome.0.0l2j69i59j69i60j0l2.1754j0j7/url?q=https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/
```

Which is basically another URL.

Let's write a little helper function which gets a parameter from a raw URL text:

```
func getParam(raw, param string) (string, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse(raw)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    q := u.Query()
    if q == nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("No query part")
    }

    v := q.Get(param)
    if v == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Param not found")
    }
    return v, nil
}
```

Using this we can get the `"aqs"` parameter from the original URL, and using this again we can get the `"q"` parameter which is exactly your desired URL:

```
raw := "https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mh4u%20items&oq=mh4u%20items&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i59j69i60j0l2.1754j0j7/url?q=https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/&sa=U&ei=n8NvVdSvBMOsyATSzYKoCQ&ved=0CEUQFjAL&usg=AFQjCNGyD5NjsqOncyLElJt9C0hqVQ7gyA"
aqs, err := getParam(raw, "aqs")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(aqs)

result, err := getParam(aqs, "q")
fmt.Println(result)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dwLYcpu00N)):

```
chrome.0.0l2j69i59j69i60j0l2.1754j0j7/url?q=https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/
https://youknowumsayin.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-inventory-and-you-what-items-should-i-bring-mh4u/
```

Comment: Wow this is really interesting I never thought of doing it that way. Thanks so much! I'll play around with this to make sure I 100% understand it

Comment: i thought you meant "scraping urls from a google search page html" :p oh well